# Common Lisp: what's the best way to loop through consecutive pairs in a list?

Tags: common-lisp

Sometimes I need to loop through consecutive pairs in a list. The way I do it right now is

```
(loop for x on lst while (not (null (cdr x)))
       (do something on (car x) and (cadr x)))
```

I'm wondering if there is a better/built-in way to do this.

The reason I need this is sometimes I want, e.g. some function that add consecutive pairs

```
(1 2 3 4 5) ----> (3 5 7 9)
```

Is there any built-in function like reduce which allow me to get this?

Comment: Why am I getting down vote on this? Is this a wrong question to ask?

Comment: Not my downvote, but possibly because your pseudocode doesn't run, yet looks sufficiently like real CL that someone was fooled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't a built-in function to do what you want. You could try to put something together with `maplist`, but my first instinct would be to reach for `loop` too.

Just a couple of notes on what you've got there though. First, `(not (null foo))` is equivalent to `foo` in CL, since a non-`NIL` value is treated as `t` by boolean operations. Second, `loop` can destructure its arguments, meaning you can write this more elegantly as

```
(loop for (a b) on lst while b
      collect (+ a b))
```

The `maplist` version would look something like

```
(maplist 
   (lambda (rest) 
     (when (cdr rest) 
        (+ (first rest) (second rest)))
   lst)
```

which I consider less readable (this would also return NIL as the last element of its result, rather than just ending before that).

Comment: Thanks, I like the elegant way you suggested.

Comment: Also, is it possible to enumerate **all** pairs or **unordered** pairs elegantly? Right now I'm doing `? (setf s '(1 2 3 4 5))
? (loop for x in s nconc (loop for y in (member x s) collect (list x y)))

((1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5) (2 2) (2 3) (2 4) (2 5) (3 3) (3 4) (3 5) (4 4) (4 5) (5 5))`

Comment: That kind of manipulation is usually handled more elegantly with [mapcar and friends](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#maplist). In that specific case, I'd define something like `(defun pair-with (elem list) (mapcar (lambda (a) (list elem a)) list))`, then call `(mapcon (lambda (rest) (pair-with (car rest) rest)) s)`. Getting *all pairs* would look quite similar.

Comment: So there's an implicit "&rest some-arg-not-used" in the (a b)?

Comment: @claytontstanley - I think it's a bit more complex than that, since you can do things like `(loop for (a . rest) on ...` or `(loop for (a b) in '((1 2) (3 4) ...) ...`. But for the purposes of this particular example, yes, that's basically right.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Paul Graham has a function named map-tuple in OnLisp which does this. It can move down the list by cdr, cddr, or however you please.   Here is a commented version of it. It uses his anaphoric if macro  **aif**.

```
(defun map-tuple (someList f &optional (by #'cdr))
 "(map-tuple someList f &optional (by #'cdr))
   f is a function that takes two args, returns one val (maybe)
   the map-tuple will collect all non-nil results in a list.
    example: 
(map-tuple '(1 2 3 4 5 6) (lambda (a b) (format T \"a: ~A b:~A~%\" a b)) #'cdr) 
a: 1 b:2
a: 2 b:3
a: 3 b:4
a: 4 b:5
a: 5 b:6
a: 6 b:NIL

(map-tuple '(1 2 3 4 5 6) (lambda (a b) (format T \"a: ~A b:~A~%\" a b)) #'cddr) 
a: 1 b:2
a: 3 b:4
a: 5 b:6
"
  (cond ((null someList)
        nil)
    (T
       (aif (funcall f (car someList) (cadr someList))
          (cons it (map-tuple (funcall by someList) f by))
           (map-tuple (funcall by someList) f by)))))
```

Comment: Relying on tail-recursion being optimised into loops is a bad idea. The standard explicitly says that it's not guaranteed to be done, and in fact SBCL doesn't even do it unless you enable optimisation. The loop solution is much better.