# Common lisp: loop through pairs of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a list who's length is divisible by two, and I'm looking for something similar to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905723/common-lisp-whats-the-best-way-to-loop-through-consecutive-pairs-in-a-list) question:

```
(loop for (a b) on lst while b
      collect (+ a b))
```

However there is overlap between elements:

```
(1 2 3 4 5) -> (3 5 7 9)
```

adding 1 and 2 and then 2 and 3 etc.

Where as I have a list like `(1 2 3 4)` and am looking for something like

```
((1 2) (3 4))
```

as output. Is there a way to make loop step correctly over the list?
Another solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(let ((list '(1 2 3 4)))
  (loop :for (a b) :on list :by #'cddr :while b 
        :collect (cons a b)))
```

Also a more verbose variant:

```
(let ((list '(1 2 3 4)))
  (loop :for a :in list :by #'cddr
        :for b :in (cdr list) :by #'cddr
        :collect (cons a b)))
```

Comment: this can get unbearably slow, is there perhaps a non loop macro variant for this that might be faster?

Comment: @cheshirecatalyst Sorry, not sure what you mean. It should be as fast as other looping options (dolist, mapcar etc.), the fact that the ":by" keyword is used shouldn't make the loop slower, actually it will do twice less steps.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach using the  [SERIES](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node347.html) package.
See also the [user manual](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-1082.pdf) from Richard C. Waters.

#### Setup

```
(ql:quickload :series)
(defpackage :stackoverflow (:use :series :cl))
(in-package :stackoverflow)
```

#### Code

```
(defun pairs (list)
  (collect 'list
    (mapping (((odd even) (chunk 2 2 (scan 'list list))))
      (list odd even))))
```

- `scan` the content of `list` as a "serie"
- `chunk` it with M=2 and N=2:

  > This function has the effect of breaking up the input series items
  >   into (possibly overlapping) chunks of length m. The starting positions
  >   of successive chunks differ by n. The inputs m and n must both be
  >   positive integers.

  More precisely, `(chunk 2 2 (scan '(1 2 3 4)))` produces `#Z(1 3)` and `#Z(2 4)`
- `mapping` in parallel over each `odd` and `even` element of those series, produce a series of couples, as done by `(list odd even)`.
- finally, `collect` the result, as a list.

#### Compilation

All the intermediate "series" are compiled away thanks to a stream-fusion mechanism. Here is the macro expansion when pointing at `collect`:

```
(LET* ((#:OUT-1120 LIST))
  (LET (#:ELEMENTS-1117
        (#:LISTPTR-1118 #:OUT-1120)
        (#:COUNT-1113 0)
        #:CHUNK-1114
        #:CHUNK-1115
        #:ITEMS-1123
        (#:LASTCONS-1106 (LIST NIL))
        #:LST-1107)
    (DECLARE (TYPE LIST #:LISTPTR-1118)
             (TYPE FIXNUM #:COUNT-1113)
             (TYPE CONS #:LASTCONS-1106)
             (TYPE LIST #:LST-1107))
    (SETQ #:COUNT-1113 1)
    (SETQ #:LST-1107 #:LASTCONS-1106)
    (TAGBODY
     #:LL-1124
      (IF (ENDP #:LISTPTR-1118)
          (GO SERIES::END))
      (SETQ #:ELEMENTS-1117 (CAR #:LISTPTR-1118))
      (SETQ #:LISTPTR-1118 (CDR #:LISTPTR-1118))
      (SETQ #:CHUNK-1114 #:CHUNK-1115)
      (SETQ #:CHUNK-1115 #:ELEMENTS-1117)
      (COND ((PLUSP #:COUNT-1113) (DECF #:COUNT-1113) (GO #:LL-1124))
            (T (SETQ #:COUNT-1113 1)))
      (SETQ #:ITEMS-1123
              ((LAMBDA (ODD EVEN) (LIST ODD EVEN)) #:CHUNK-1114 #:CHUNK-1115))
      (SETQ #:LASTCONS-1106
              (SETF (CDR #:LASTCONS-1106) (CONS #:ITEMS-1123 NIL)))
      (GO #:LL-1124)
     SERIES::END)
    (CDR #:LST-1107)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CL-USER 156 > (loop with list = '(1 2 3 4)
                    while list
                    collect (loop repeat 2
                                  while list
                                  collect (pop list)))
((1 2) (3 4))
```

or

```
CL-USER 166 > (loop with list = '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
                    while (and list (cdr list))
                    collect (loop repeat 2 collect (pop list)))
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))

CL-USER 167 > (loop with list = '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
                    while (and list (cdr list))
                    collect (loop repeat 2 collect (pop list)))
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
```